# Transform a Sum into a List

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to turn a sum like this

```
sum =a-b+c+d
```

Into a List like this:

```
sumToList[sum]={a,-b,c,d}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am a professor of "vectorial analysis" in Mexico. I try to teach the subjects with the use of "Mathematica". I solved a problem seeing this page and also this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100758/finding-scalar-potential-function/100763 ... in which I was not allowed to comment. This was what I did to find the "scalar potential function". https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugIlP.png

Comment: @David I converted your answer to a comment, as it seems more appropriate as such.  I know that new users do not have the ["privilege"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to comment everywhere (a "spam" control measure I believe) but if you continue to participate you will find that you soon do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
List @@ sum
```

> {a, -b, c, d}

From the docs on [Apply (@@)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html):

> f@@*expr* replaces the head of *expr* by f.

So `List@@sum` replaces `Head[sum]` (that is, `Plus`) with `List`.

You can also get the same result by changing `0`th `Part` of `sum` (which is its `Head`) to `List`:

```
sum[[0]] = List; sum
```

> {a, -b, c, d}

Comment: There is a slight hiccup that you can encounter using this. If you're not explicitly doing a sum, you will list over whatever the head of the function is. e.g. `List @@ 2*3` will result in `{2,3}`

Comment: @AlexDB, you are right; `List@@expr` does change the head of `expr`, whatever it is, to `List`.

Comment: So what's the most general way to make a list, so that we include both distinct cases where there is one and multiple terms?

Answer (score 12):

Try :

```
a - b + c + d /. Plus -> List
```

You can have a look at `a - b + c + d //FullForm` to see why this works.

Comment: Good one.  And maybe `sum[[0]] = List; sum`

Comment: @TomD that is the one I like to use :)

Answer (score 7):

Still another route:

```
Last[CoefficientArrays[#]] Variables[#] &[a - b + c + d]
   {a, -b, c, d}
```