# Simplifying general solutions of differential equations (driven harmonic oscillator)

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

Solving general differential equations in Mathematica usually leads to somewhat unsightly results.

As an example, consider the solution of the driven, damped harmonic oscillator:

```
eqn = x''[t] + β x'[t] +  ω0^2 x[t] == f0/m Exp[I ωd t];
s = DSolve[eqn, x[t], t]
```

[image: Unsightly long result]

Using `FullSimplify` helps to reduce this mess, but the result is still far away from something an engineer or physicist would recognize at first glance:

```
Simplify[s]
```

[image: Weirdly simplified result]

How can you transform such solutions into something nicer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to your own answer there is a much simpler form that you may use, recalling:

> `Collect[expr, var, h]` applies *h* to the expression that forms the
>   coefficient of each term obtained.

```
sol = x[t] /. s[[1]];

Collect[sol, _C, Simplify]
```

> ```
> (E^(I t ωd) f0)/(m ω0^2 + I m β ωd - m ωd^2) + 
>  E^(-(1/2) t (β + Sqrt[β^2 - 4 ω0^2])) C[1] + 
>  E^(1/2 t (-β + Sqrt[β^2 - 4 ω0^2])) C[2]
> ```

---

Martin commented:

> It's unfortunate that `FullSimplify` doesn't do this step on its own. The leaf-count is actually lower after collecting on the `C[i]`.

One can add manipulations using [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) therefore:

```
collectC[x_] := Collect[x, _C, Simplify]
SetOptions[FullSimplify, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, collectC}];

FullSimplify[sol]
```

> ```
> (E^(I t ωd) f0)/(m ω0^2 + I m β ωd - m ωd^2) + 
>  E^(-(1/2) t (β + Sqrt[β^2 - 4 ω0^2])) C[1] + 
>  E^(1/2 t (-β + Sqrt[β^2 - 4 ω0^2])) C[2]
> ```

Comment: This is a nice and general method for linear differential equations because the `C[i]` will always be multiplicative in front of the homogeneous solutions, so collecting them is the natural choice (+1).

Comment: It's unfortunate that `FullSimplify` doesn't do this step on its own. The leaf-count is actually lower after collecting on the `C[i]`.

Comment: The result of collecting over `m` is smaller, but not very systematic because `m` is a variable that could easily be eliminated from the entire problem. A more systematic way of getting that same result seems to be  `Simplify /@ Apart@Simplify[sol]`. Here I use the fact that `Map` can also work on expressions that don't have head `List` - which is also something the OP could have used to avoid converting to `List` initially. But I think what the physicist expects is really the result of collecting over `_C`...

Comment: @Jens Points taken.

Comment: @Jens I updated my answer to work on `_C` but I did not introduce `Apart`.  Do you feel like posting that yourself?

Comment: I really think the `_C` approach is unbeatable, so this should be the accepted answer. So I'll just leave it up to you if you want to mention `Apart`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to tackle the problem is to recognize that the solution is one giant sum with three terms.

You can then [convert this sum to a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13432/transform-a-sum-into-a-list), simplify the terms individually, and sum all elements of the list back together.

```
sol = x[t] /. s[[1]];
Total[ FullSimplify[ Apply[ List , sol  ] ] ]
```

[image: Nicer solution]

But this "hack" is somewhat unelegant, because it might fail if the inhomogeneous solution is a sum in it's own.

A more robust solution is to `Simplify` first, then `Collect` all terms that contain a `C[ ]`-factor, and finally simplifying the individual terms in that sum:

```
sol = x[t] /. s[[1]];
Total [Simplify[Apply[List, Collect[ Simplify[ sol ], _C  ] ] ] ]
```

It's a bit hard to see what is going in that verbose form, so here is the same code in postfix notation (think "Unix pipes"):

```
sol = x[t] /. s[[1]];
sol // Simplify // Collect[#, _C]&   // Apply[List, #]&   // Simplify // Total
```

The output of all these commands is equivalent.

**Addendum**: I did another `FullSimplify` of the last result and noticed that it stayed the same (instead of reverting to the original). And indeed, [checking the complexity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26172/how-do-i-invoke-the-default-complexity-function) of the expressions revealed *121* for the original "FullSimplified"-version, and *90* for the "Collected" version.

I suspect that `FullSimplify` somehow misses this simplification. Hopefully it will come in future Mathematica versions.

Comment: For a very simple form, set the arbitrary constants to zero: `s[[1]] /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0} // Simplify`

Comment: It's a valid trick, but you have to be careful that you don't lose information that you care about: In the harmonic oscillator example, setting the `C`s to 0 gets rid of the transients and leaves you with the steady state solution.

Comment: Another way to write your last line of code, assuming M10 operator forms: `Simplify[sol] ~Collect~ C[_] // Apply[List] // Simplify // Total`