# Finding scalar potential function

Tags: vector-calculus

Consider the vector field defined by:
$$\vec F(x,y)=\langle 2xy-\sin x,x^2+e^{3y}\rangle$$
We can check to see if the vector field is conservative with the following calculations:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+e^{3y})=2x\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2xy-\sin x)=2x\\
\end{align*}$$
Now, I am interested in looking at several different procedures for finding a scalar function $f(x,y)$ such that $\vec F(x,y)=\nabla f(x,y)$. Can folks share their ideas?

**Update:** Sure, students need to attack this by hand in class in the following manner.

$$\begin{align*}
\vec F(x,y)&=\nabla f(x,y)\\
\langle 3+2xy, x^2-3y^2\rangle&=\langle\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y\rangle
\end{align*}$$

They start by setting
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3+2xy,$$
then integrate with respect to $x$.
$$f(x,y)=3x+x^2y+h(y)$$
The second step is to set:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&=x^2-3y^2\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(3x+x^2y+h(y))&=x^2-3y^2\\
x^2+h'(y)&=x^2-3y^2
\end{align*}$$
The last line gives us
$$h'(y)=-3y^2,$$
then integrating gives us
$$h(y)=-y^3.$$
Subbing this into $f(x,y)=3x+x^2y+h(y)$ gives the final answer.
$$f(x,y)=3x+x^2y-y^3$$

So I am trying:

```
Clear[f, h, x, y, p, q]
p = 3 + 2 x y;
q = x^2 - 3 y^2;
```

Then I perform the conservative test:

```
D[p, y]
D[q, x]
```

Which gives:

```
(* 2x *)

(* 2x *)
```

So we do have a conservative vector field. Next:

```
f=Integrate[p,x]+h[y]
```

Which gives:

```
(* 3 x + x^2 y + h[y] *)
```

Next, I run:

```
Solve[D[f, y] == q, h'[y]]
```

Which gives:

```
(* {{Derivative[1][h][y] -> -3 y^2}} *)
```

Then I do this:

```
Integrate[-3 y^2, y]
```

Which gives:

```
(* -y^3 *)
```

Then I do this:

```
f = f /. h[y] -> -y^3
```

Which gives the final answer:

```
(* 3 x + x^2 y - y^3 *)
```

I love the answers I have received thus far, but would also like to see what folks do to purify my attempt.

Comment: See also [100521](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100561/1063).

Comment: The approach in your update seems quite reasonable to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical approach is

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, y], x] == 2 x y - Sin[x], D[f[x, y], y] == x^2 + Exp[3 y]}, f[x, y], {x, y}]
(* {{f[x, y] -> E^(3 y)/3 + x^2 y + C[1] + Cos[x]}} *)
```

Note that, if the vector field were not conservative, `DSolve` would return unevaluated.

Comment: Short and simple; it gets my upvote. (But I am a little concerned that `DSolve` might be checking the political views of its arguments..)

Comment: @bbgodfrey A very elegant approach. This is definitely an approach I will use in class tomorrow with my students. It will also give those students who will take differential equations next semester a nice introductory look to the DSolve command.

Comment: @bbgodfrey - this is a helpful piece of code. How would you extend it to (x,y,z), a 3 variable equation. I tried to play around with this code, which I got to work for 2D equations, but could't get it to work for 3-D when I added a z component where it seemed right. Thoughts?

Comment: @user27847  I believe that my approach does not generalize well to 3D.  You might wish to ask a question based on your particular case.

Answer (score 4):

Very elegant bbgodfrey; here is another method:

```
eq1 = Integrate[2 x y - Sin[x], x] // Expand;
eq2 = Integrate[x^2 + Exp[3 y], y] // Expand;
DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[List @@@ {eq1, eq2}] // Total

E^(3 y)/3 + x^2 y + Cos[x]
```

Comment: Another very interesting approach. This again helps me understand the @@@, the Flatten, and DeleteDuplicates commands. Extremely helpful. Thanks.